# Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this vb.net code?

Tags: excel, vb.net

I have written following.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Function EachSubTotal(ByVal x As Excel.Range, ByVal y As Excel.Range) As Double
    Dim ReturnValue As Double
    Dim Done As Boolean
    Done = False
    ReturnValue = -1

    If y.Value2 = "*" And IsNumeric(x.Value2) Then
        ReturnValue = x.Value2 / 1.1025
        Done = True
    ElseIf (y.Value2 >= 0) And IsNumeric(x.Value2) Then
        ReturnValue = x.Value2 * (1 - y.Value2)
        Done = True
    ElseIf (y.Value2 < 0) And IsNumeric(x.Value2) Then
        ReturnValue = x.Value2 * (1 + y.Value2)
        Done = True
    End If

    If Not Done And String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Value2) Then
        ReturnValue = -2
    End If

    Return Math.Round(ReturnValue, 2)

End Function
```

Now problem is that as soon as y has some numerical value, I get #Value error.  Why?
Thanks in advance

Above code is to be used in dll which is imported to Excel.

So I am posting this for others who may run into similar problem.

```
 Public Function EachSubTotal(ByVal x As Excel.Range, ByVal y As Excel.Range) As Double
    Dim ReturnValue As Double
    Dim Done As Boolean
    Done = False
    ReturnValue = -1

    If IsNumeric(y.Value2) Then
        If (y.Value2 >= 0) And IsNumeric(x.Value2) Then
            ReturnValue = x.Value2 * (1 - y.Value2)
            Done = True
        Else
            ReturnValue = x.Value2 * (1 + y.Value2)
            Done = True
        End If
    Else
        If y.Value2 = "*" And IsNumeric(x.Value2) Then
            ReturnValue = x.Value2 / 1.1025
            Done = True
        End If
    End If

    If Not Done And String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Value2) Then
        ReturnValue = -2
    End If

    Return Math.Round(ReturnValue, 2)

End Function
```

Comment: Are you sure `y.Value2` is indeed numeric? Because if it's not and it's also different from `"*"` you try to compare it to a number, which of course fails and causes an error

Comment: You need to debug your code and, if necessary, report to us what you find.

Comment: Thanks, guys.  To be more specific, when y.Value2 has value of "*", it works fine.  And when the cell is empty, it works fine, too.  But as soon as I input some numbers, it shows #value error.  I have been working on it for couple of days, and it just stomped me clueless.

Comment: You are acting as though your are a user and just reporting what you see in the UI. You're not a user. You're the developer. You need to use the development tools at your disposal. Debug the code. Look at what the code actually does in the specific instance you describe. If you don't know how to debug then stop what you're doing and learn that first, then apply what you've learned here. You should be able to tell us the value of every variable and exactly what path execution takes through the code when the error occurs. You should have been able to tell us that before posting the question.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, howdy, mate.  Little grouch this morning?  LOL.  Obviously, running and checking with debug was first thing.  And that turned out little.  That is why I am asking for help.  However, I did manage to solve the problem.  It wasn't problem with VB.Net but problem with Excel.  I did an ADO project while ago, and did remember that values in cells in Excel is set to whatever data type that you worked on first.  So I did change codes, and it works dandy.  I will post the code for other to see when I figure it out how to do so.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ok...  As I stated above, "I did manage to the problem".   I post the solution as second set of codes for anyone who may counter similar problem as I did.